# Not able to Install Unity in VS2010

Tags: unity-container

I am trying to install Unity from Nugget in VS2010 and receiving following error:

*Could not install package 'Unity 3.5.1404.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

Any Idea what could be Wrong?
[image]

I understand this package is not for VS2010 but for VS2012 or later. What is the way to get this package for VS2010 or VS2008?

Cheers

Comment: Following version solved the issue:Install-Package Unity -Version 2.1.505.2

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Unity 3.5 requires .NET 4.5.

Comment: You highlight the problem but provide no solution.

Comment: Really? And what solution do you thing there can be other than upgrading to .NET 4.5?

Comment: Upgrading the framework version is one solution (which at the moment is not explicitly suggested by your answer) alternatively, using a version of Unity that is compatible with .NET4.0 is another solution.

Comment: Not explicitly suggested by my answer? What is unclear about "The problem is that Unity 3.5 requires .NET 4.5."?